# Binding data of Domain model type to ViewModel type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to bind data from the database to ViewModel. Basically, I have a domain model which I find has too much properties and which I'd like to reduce so logically I've chosen ViewModel to do so.

**Domain model (automatically created from the database):**

```
public partial class Ticket
{
    public Ticket()
    {
        this.Daily = new HashSet<Daily>();
        this.Ticket1 = new HashSet<Ticket>();
    }

    public int idTicket { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> idNadredeniTicket { get; set; }
    public short RedniBroj { get; set; }
    public int idFirma { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> idKontakt { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> idManager { get; set; }
    public string Tip { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DatumPrijave { get; set; }
    public string VrstaPrijave { get; set; }
    public string Prioritet { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DatumDo { get; set; }
    public string Opis { get; set; }
    public string Biljeske { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Zatvoren { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IzdanRacun { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DatumZatvaranja { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> idAsset { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Daily> Daily { get; set; }
    public virtual Firma Firma { get; set; }
    public virtual Kontakt Kontakt { get; set; }
    public virtual Kontakt Kontakt1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Ticket1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Ticket Ticket2 { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class OpenTickets
{
    public int idTicket { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> idNadredeniTicket { get; set; }
    public short RedniBroj { get; set; }
    public int idFirma { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> idKontakt { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> idManager { get; set; }
    public string Tip { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DatumPrijave { get; set; }
    public string VrstaPrijave { get; set; }
    public string Prioritet { get; set; }
    public string Opis { get; set; }
    public string Biljeske { get; set; }

    public string BrojTicketa
    {
        get
        {
            return idNadredeniTicket.ToString() + "-" + RedniBroj.ToString();
        }
    }
    public string NazivTicketa
    {
        get
        {
            return BrojTicketa + " - " + Opis;
        }
    }
    public string DetaljiTicketa
    {
        get
        {
            return Opis + "\r\n" + Biljeske;
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like to accomplish is to bind data from the database via query to the ViewModel but, understandingly, I get errors regarding different types of objects passed to the View. I'm posting controller and view for the reference.

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult OpenTickets()
    {
        var openTickets = db.Ticket
            .Where(t => t.idFirma == 1)
            .Where(t => t.Zatvoren == false);

        return View(openTickets.ToList());
    }
```

**View (some code is intentionally ommited for brevity)**

```
@model IEnumerable<IDE3_CRM.ViewModels.OpenTickets>

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Biljeske)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Opis)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend wrapping your db calls in a `Repository`. In here, you can transform your database objects into view models. For example:

```
public ActionResult OpenTickets()
{
    var openTickets = ticketRepo.GetOpenTickets();
    return View(openTickets);
}

// Implementation of ITicketRepo
public IEnumerable<OpenTickets> GetOpenTickets()
{
    return db.Ticket
        .Where(t => t.idFirma == 1 && t.Zatvoren == false)
        .Select(do => new OpenTickets
        {
            // Fill in view model properties from database object
        });
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, just one more thing. It seems that the custom properties from OpenTicket.cs aren't recognized e.g. BrojTicketa, NazivTicketa, DetaljiTicketa. Any info on that? @beautifulcoder

Comment: Thanks, figured out that by adding `set` they appear as I expected to.

Answer (score 1):

Hrvach,

You can limit the data fields in the view itself and I think that maybe more efficient. That being said here is another approach you can take:

1. Create a list of type OpenTickets
2. Select the tickets you want
3. Loop over the selected tickets and add a new openTicket with the
   properites you want to keep to the list of openTickets
4. return the list of open tickets

   ```
   public ActionResult OpenTickets()
   {


       List<OpenTickets> openTicketList = new List<OpenTickets>();//create a list of openTickets

       var Tickets = db.Ticket//select the tickets that you want
           .Where(t => t.idFirma == 1)
           .Where(t => t.Zatvoren == false);

       foreach (var ticket in Tickets)//Loop over the tickets and create an openTicket out of each ticket then add the openTick to the openTicketList
       {
           OpenTickets openTicket = new OpenTickets();//create new OpenTickets object
           openTicket.propery1 = ticket.propery1;//set each property of the openTicket equal to the property of the Ticket that you want to keep
           openTicket.propery2 = ticket.propery2;
           openTicket.propery3 = ticket.propery3;
           openTicket.propery4 = ticket.propery4;
           openTicketList.Add(openTicket);//add new OpenTickets object to the list
       }
       return View(openTicketList);
   }
   ```

I hope this helps...Best wishes 
Bill

Comment: That's very helpful and like the answer below it is also the answer, however, I prefer @beautifulcoders answer over yours for just one thing; it automatically provides properties. Thank you once again!